# Do I need to write custom proxy handling code for OkHttp on Android?

Tags: android, okhttp

We're about to switch our HTTP stack from Apache HttpClient to OkHttp. One piece of code we still have in place is a broadcast receiver that detects changes to the network proxy, and updates HttpClient manually to route HTTP(s) requests through that proxy.

I'm not sure whether we still need to handle that manually with OkHttp?

Quoting from the docs of `setProxySelector`:

> If unset, the system-wide default proxy selector will be used.

Looking at [0], it sounds like we're covered, since OkHttp uses the the system-wide selector by default which in turn makes sure proxy system properties are reflected back into the OkHttp routes?

[0] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. OkHttp will automatically use the appropriate proxy. You can test this yourself with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), following [these instructions](http://jaanus.com/blog/2012/02/12/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/).